# Не могу создать двусвязный список со стринговыми данными

Tags: c++, двусвязный-список

Проблема в том что когда выделяю память под новый узел в двусвязном списке, то при присваивании стринговой переменной name строку, вылетает ошибка: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу

```
void push(ELEMENT* list, int num_b, int num_r, string n)
{
ELEMENT* p;
p = (ELEMENT*)malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT));
p->number_bus = num_b;
p->number_route = num_r;
p->name = n;
insert(list, p);
}
```

Вот сама структура узла

```
typedef struct ELEMENT
{
int number_bus;
int number_route;
string name;
ELEMENT* next;
ELEMENT* past;
}ELEMENT;
```

Когда убираю переменную name или ничего ей не присваиваю то всё работает.
Хотел бы понять почему так происходит и как это исправить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если коротко, вместо функции `malloc` следует использовать оператор `new` для создания новых объектов:

```
void push(ELEMENT* list, int num_b, int num_r, string n)
{
    ELEMENT* p;
    p = new ELEMENT;
    //...
}
```

Функция `malloc` - это Си функция, она ничего не знает об объектах С++ и их конструкторах.
Она просто выделяет кусок сырой неинициализированной памяти. Проще говоря, после

```
p = (ELEMENT*)malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT));
```

область, на которую указывает `p`, не содержит никакого объекта типа `string`,
лишь участок выделенной памяти, в котором еще предстоит его создать.
Оператор `new`, в свою очередь, помимо выделения памяти, вызывает конструктор объекта (и его членов).
Таким образом, вновь созданный объект типа `ELEMENT` будет содержать объект типа `string`.
P.S. Не забудьте, что объекты, созданные оператором `new` должны удаляться с помощью оператора `delete`.
Т.е., если Вы выделяли память с помощью `malloc`, а освобождали с помощью `free`, то, при создании объектов
с помощью `new`, удалять их нужно с помощью `delete`.

Comment: Разница есть. И вызывает он не только отсутствующий (дефолтный) конструктор структуры, но и конструктор строки, который может быть не тривиальным. В случае с `malloc` - там мусор, а не строка. И присваивание этому мусору вызовет деструктор "мусора" - что произойдет? Так что сначала нужно разобраться с правильным созданием объекта, а уж потом копать далее в `insert`.

Comment: Да, скорее всего так и есть, ибо в строке `p->name = n` для объекта `name` вызывается оператор `=` и на нём всё валится, так как объект должным образом непроинициализирован. Как-то упустил этот момент из виду.

Comment: *Вернее не деструктор, а перераспределение памяти в строке (при присваивании) (поправил себя выше)

Comment: Если 'p', не содержит никакого объекта типа 'string' и по этому всё не работает, то почему всё работает с типом 'int'?

Comment: Потому что `int` - тривиальный тип и его не нужно "конструировать".